# Boosting a microphone on Windows 7 beyond the limit that which windows provides

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I'm looking for a software / hack to boost a microphone in Windows 7 64bit, beyond the limit that which windows gives.

In Ventrilo for example, I can boost my microphone even more than it's current level which allows people to easily able to hear me.

Now if we look at Skype, either on auto or on max people can hear me perfectly without any boost.

As for other softwares for example Steam, Teamviewer they can't hear me very well it's always very quiet.

Here are my sound settings for the microphone which is a webcam microphone (lovely and clear, no fuzz, background noise or anything)

Any ideas how I can boost the output level more?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/auCPmPt.png]

Microphone 1 (Webcam)
 - Great sound quality, just too quiet on Steam and other programs however it works beautifully on Skype for example.

Microphone 2 (Bluetooth Headphones)
- Sounds like I'm underwater and really quiet.

Microphone 3 (Bluetooth Portable Speaker)
- Picks up too much background noise

Microphone 4 (Speedlink Medusa Nx)
- Apparent fuzz and also quiet

Microphone 5 (Phone, Nexus 4)
- Sounds crackly and quiet

Comment: You shouldn't have to boot your Microphone to 100% for people to barely hear you.  Have you considered getting yourself a different type of Microphone, one that can be placed closer to your mouth, will prevent the "empty room effect" more then likely.  Steam and Team viewer both have their tools to boost your Microphone but again if the windows setting is set to max and that happens there is something else wrong.

Comment: I have four other potential uses for a microphone but all have their downsides, I've edited to give a list of potential microphones that I have.

Comment: How are you using a speaker as a microphone exactly?  Yes I understand how you do it electronically

Comment: @Ramhound It's got a microphone in it "SoundWave SW100" is the product.

Answer (score 0):

I originally got a powered external USB hub which solved my Samson C01U problem for a few years. Then something changed, and I suddenly lost the volume. I've been using the C01U for over five years on a Windows 7 laptop and struggled with the low volume problem. Recently I had to format and reinstall Windows - but that did not fix it for me.

I just installed two pieces of software (Equalizer APO and the Peace GUI), and it solved my low volume problem!

https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/peace-equalizer-apo-extension/

Today I posted a youtube video example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI7VuvxPPUM